# PHP MYSQL search always brings back 0 results

Tags: php, search, mysqli

Hello Im trying to write a search function in php, but I always get 0 results found.

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'testing123', 'test') 
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Error : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
} 
//collect
$output = '';
if(isset($_POST['search'])){
    $searchq = $_POST['search'];
    $searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$searchq);
    $query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UsernameLIKE '%$searchq%'");
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    // if the $result contains at least one row
    if ($query->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row from $result
        while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        }
    }
    else {
        echo '0 results';
    }
}    
?>
```

Any ideas how to fix?

EDIT 1. This still does not allow it to be worked out with even this commented out.

```
if(!empty($_POST['search'])){
    $searchq = $_POST['search'];
    //$searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$searchq);
    $query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username LIKE '$searchq%'");
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    // if the $result contains at least one row
    if ($query->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row from $result
        while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        }
    }
    else {
        echo '0 results';
    }
}
```

Comment: Tell me if pasting `SELECT * FROM School WHERE SchoolName LIKE '%Cal Poly%'` returns anything(or some search term similar to get results).

Comment: [link](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php#105289) this note on php.net may help. Also looks like you're calling num_rows twice, don't think that's necessary.

Comment: This should work. Post your HTML form.

Comment: @JoeM Then the problem is with the search query and not this page. can you add an example row from your table?

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything, 
 as well as `or die(mysqli_error($mysqli))` to `mysqli_query()`.

Comment: @ViperCode http://imgur.com/uwLWvAy

Comment: if you run this query what gets returned? SELECT * FROM School WHERE SchoolName LIKE '%School%'

Comment: @ViperCode The school is shown as expected

Comment: how about if you use this string instead in your php file? `"SELECT * FROM School WHERE SchoolName LIKE '%".$searchq."%'"`

Comment: the problem's with your table; your code's fine. what are you entering into the input to search for and are your columns the right type? use what I gave you above to test for errors. and instead of `if(isset($_POST['search'])){` you're best using `if(!empty($_POST['search'])){`

Comment: The datatypes are all varchars  and still return 0 results.

Comment: my comment was a 2-part question, you answered one. #2) what are you entering into the input to search for?

Comment: I am searching for School Name 1

Comment: search for just the word School and I'm next to convinced you'll get a result. What you're trying to find now is an exact match and your method doesn't seem to allow that. If so, change your query to `WHERE SchoolName LIKE '$searchq%'"`, but do try entering just the word School

Comment: Fred, you are correct. If i search for school it does come up. How do i change my query so that is will allow me to type in anything and it will return? For example I want to type in School Name 1 and get it to return that school.

Comment: you need an exact match for that, and you won't be using `LIKE` for that, but just an `=` as in `WHERE SchoolName = '$searchq'"` but `WHERE SchoolName LIKE '$searchq%'"`, may also work for it. Typing "anything" depends on what that is though. Define: anything.

Comment: This time it returns 0 results. By anything I mean typing School, School Name, or School Name 1

Comment: then you may have a space at the end of your row's value. `WHERE SchoolName LIKE '$searchq%'"` should work though for School, School Name, or School Name 1

Comment: It still returns 0 results. On School Name 1. And I can confirm there is no additional spaces anywhere

Comment: I know why; it's because of this `[^0-9a-z]` in  `$searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$searchq);` comment it out and it will work. Once that does, I will post an answer if you wish.

Comment: It now has increased functionality, however it still does not allow for searching of anything that is not the first word. So if School is not at the start of the search, it will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to match School, School Name, or School Name 1

Your query needs to read as and removing the starting `%` and just keeping the trailing `%`

```
WHERE SchoolName LIKE '$searchq%'"
```

Now, the reason why it's not finding School Name and School Name 1 is because it contains spaces and your regex is replacing those spaces by nothing.

```
$searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$searchq);
```

- Either comment that line out or modify the regex.

By commenting it out, you can revert back to using:

```
WHERE SchoolName LIKE '%$searchq%'"
```

Comment: Having commented out the line, it still does not work as intended, as it still shows 0 results
 
I have updated the original post, as its too long for a comment

Comment: @JoeM I made an edit, reload it to see the bottom line

Comment: @JoeM I saw your edit but you didn't reload my answer. Look under "By commenting it out, you can revert back to using:"  `WHERE SchoolName LIKE '%$searchq%'"`

Comment: Tried, Again no difference. Even  School Name 1 does not work with the % at the start

Comment: @JoeM I have **John name 1** in my db and tested it with "john" and "name" and "1" even "john name" and "John name 1", all of which worked. I can't see why yours wouldn't. Are you sure you don't have a caching problem? you did update your file right?

Comment: Im sorry, this was a massive mess up by me. I was putting the extra % after the $ sign instead! My bad, thanks for the assistance though! Thanks!

Comment: @JoeM Ok. Well, if you think my answer is worth keeping alive, you could mark it as solved then. I'm glad this was resolved, *cheers* and you're welcome.

Comment: i was going to  suggest `->store_result()` by a long shot, but it was just typo all along. lol :D

Comment: @Ghost hehe yeah that would've been great. I'm glad it was just a typo. Hope you're doing well my friend :-)